# Include Extern Variable inside Method PHP

Tags: php, global-variables, require-once

I have this code:

```
//config.php
$EXAMPLE['try1'] = "...." ;
$EXAMPLE['try2'] = "...." ;
```

So, i have another file with a php class:

```
class try {
   public function __construct() {
       if($this->try1() && $this->try2()){
            return true;
       }
   }
   public function try1(){
   require_once 'config.php' ;
   echo $EXAMPLE['try1'];
   return true;
   }
   public function try2(){
   require_once 'config.php' ;
   echo $EXAMPLE['try2'];
   return true;
   }
}
```

But in my case, `$EXAMPLE['try1']` is ..... , but `$EXAMPLE['try2']` is null... why? I've tried to include `require_once 'config.php' ;` on top page, and add after `global $EXAMPLE;` , but `$EXAMPLE` is ever null, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `require`, not `require_once`. Otherwise, if you load the file in one function, it won't be loaded in the other function, so it won't get the variables.

It would be better to require the function outside the functions entirely. Then declare `$EXAMPLE` as a global variable.

```
require_once 'config.php';

class try {
    public function __construct() {
        if($this->try1() && $this->try2()){
            return true;
        }
    }
    public function try1(){
        global $EXAMPLE
        echo $EXAMPLE['try1'];
        return true;
    }
    public function try2(){
        global $EXAMPLE
        echo $EXAMPLE['try2'];
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Require your file inside `__construct` method. So require once requires file once in `try1` method.

```
class try {

    private $_example = array();

    public function __construct() {

        require_once 'config.php';

        $this->_example = $EXAMPLE;

        return $this->try1() && $this->try2();
    }

     public function try1(){
        echo $this->_example['try1'];
        return true;
     }

     public function try2(){
        echo $this->_example['try2'];
        return true;
     }
}
```

Comment: Do not forget to check array keys if they are isset: `isset($this->_example['try1'])`;